# How do I run a Python 3.5 program that uses Tkinter on a computer without Python installed?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I have coded a program in Python 3.5 that uses the Tkinter import. I'm trying to figure out a way to run it on computers that don't have Python. First I tried freezing it but I haven't been able to because none of the freezing tools I found support Python 3.5. Then I tried possibly using a online idle but I couldn't find any that support Tkinter. I would prefer to be able to get a .exe file or something similar but if I could run it online that would be good too any ideas?

**EDIT**

So I have now successfully downloaded PyInstaller using pip. My current problem is when I type this into the console: pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed Finder.py
I get this error: 'pyinstaller.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**EDIT**
I have now found the pathway to pyinstaller.exe. Now when I try to use it it says Access is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out after about three days of work. Fist I downloaded PyInstaleller in the zipped form and extracted it. Then I put my program in the PyInstaller folder. Then I opened a regular command prompt. I then typed cd then the location of the PyInstaller folder. Finally I typed pyinstaller.py --one file --windowed program.py. Then when I went into the PyInstaller folder there was a folder called program with the .exe file in the dist folder. Thanks everyone for all of your help!

Comment: does it run on target machine or not?? cause mine won't I've tried cx_freeze pyinstaller also py2exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) to do that. I think its work fine on linux em linux.

Another option is use py2exe.

Comment: As far as I know py2exe doesn't support Python 3.5. Pyinstaller does support it however I haven't been able to get it to work for me yet. I'll keep trying to get Pyinstaller too work for now. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pyinstaller -F -w Finder.py` as the command or you could check out CxFreeze.

Comment: I tried pyinstaller -F -w Finder.py but it just said 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I might check out CxFreeze though. Thanks for the help:)