# Exporting Python 3.5 and Tkinter to EXE or MSI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I'm using Python 3.5 and would like to export my python code for me to send to others who do not have Python installed. Thing is Pyinstaller doesn't work as I get this error:[image: Pyinstaller Error]

CX_Freeze also doesn't work for me either as Tkinter still presents a problem, on running `python setup.py build` I get:

```
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

I'm getting sick of this to be frank so any help would be appreciated. Here's my imports in my code if it helps

```
import pdb
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to get it working by downloading Pyinstaller from the website and running the commands in the new folder. I followed the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40349880/5618339) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of cx_Freeze(<5.0), it doesn't have Python35 support. The latest development version has Python35 support. You can install it by

`pip install cx-Freeze-win`

But you need to have VC++ run-time installed on your system to run this successfully.

Also I've found this [GitHub-repo](https://github.com/sekrause/cx_Freeze-Wheels) with pre-built binary packages of cx_Freeze 5 for windows platform.

```
pip install wheel
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sekrause/cx_Freeze-Wheels/master/cx_Freeze-5.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: That version of cx_Freeze is the one I'm using unfortunately. Doesn't work